# Custom number in Java

Tags: java

I would like to create a custom number class in java, which after ranging from 000000 to 099999 would continue with 0A0000. So the last number would be 9Z9999.

I'm a bit lost on how I could implement this in Java. I suppose I would need to create a custom class which extends Number.

My goal would be to create a class on which I could iterate through (from 000000 to 9Z9999) to reserve document ID ranges.

Although I could do achieve this end with several other workarounds, I find this to be the cleanest solution.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: This seems somewhat confusing, I can understand this being a non base 10 number (base 36? (10+26)) but why does **only** the 5th digit go between 0 and Z not all the digits?

Comment: Now that I look at this closer you're not suggesting a number at all, but a "word", Remember a credit card "number" is a word made up of digits not a number because it makes not sense to add/subtract/divide/multiply a credit card number

Comment: You might consider implementing a custom class that extends NumberFormat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work. Just use an ordinary number and format it:

```
static String asStrangeNumber ( int i ) {
  // Lowest 4 digits are decimal.
  int low4 = i%10000;
  i /= 10000;
  // Next is base 36 - 0-9-A-Z
  int c = i % 36;
  i /= 36;
  // Remaining should be < 10.
  return String.format("%1d%c%04d", i%10, c < 10 ? '0' + c: 'A' + c - 10, low4);
}

public void test() {
  test (0);
  test (1);
  test (10);
  test (100);
  test (1000);
  test (10000);
  test (100000);
  test (1000000);

}

private void test(int i) {
  System.out.println("    "+i+" -> "+asStrangeNumber(i));
}
```

prints

```
0 -> 000000
1 -> 000001
10 -> 000010
100 -> 000100
1000 -> 001000
10000 -> 010000
100000 -> 0A0000
1000000 -> 2S0000
```

Comment: A was originally looking into a solution in which I create a custom class, so that I do not have to map ints to strings, but I'll look through this solution on more depth, thank you.

Comment: Very nice little program...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes sense. `Number` defines methods like `intValue()` etc., and how can you convert `0Z0000` to `int`?

Just create your own `CustomId` class, but don't extend `Number`.

Comment: I'm assuming 0Z0000==0(36)0000==360000, if I understand this number system correctly

Comment: well... or it is just an ID. Is there really a requirement to convert it to `int`, `long`, `float`...?

Comment: There is no real requirement on converting it to int, long, etc - I apologize for the confusion.
My only requirement would be to be able to loop through a range of instances of this class - as if looping through numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to create a single class that gives out IDs (note these are not numbers per se but words). This would contain 6 counters, each of which had a maximum value (9 for 5 of them 36 for the remaining one that has numbers and letters).

When each new ID is requested the bottom counter is increased, when it reaches it's maximum value it resets to zero and increases the next counter by one etc etc. (this counter could be its own class, with fields for currentValue and maximumValue and method increment() that increments the internal value and returns a boolean as to if the higher counter should be incremented)

Then the actual ID is outputted as a String, with each counter having it's current value converted to a single character (0-9 -->'0'-'9' 10-36 --> 'A'-'Z')